# Replace String using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, text, replace

Replacement with Regular expressions in Java - 
I have a String

```
    allof{
    condition {licenseState=="NY"}
    condition{professionId==301}
    condition  {professionId=="301"}
}
```

would be it's possible to do a replacement in java using regex so the string looks like this one:

```
    allof{
    condition 'licenseState=="NY"', {licenseState=="NY"}
    condition 'professionId==301', {professionId==301}
    condition 'professionId=="301"', {professionId=="301"}
    }
```

basically getting what inside the {} brackets and putting it separately. Is it possible and how? NewLine char is not guaranteed to be present after each condition.

I've tried:

```
condition\s*?{[a-zA-Z0-9=<>\s"']*}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried `code` condition\s*?{[a-zA-Z0-9=<>\s"']*} `code` which selected everything, but I don't know how to extract inner part of it

Comment: Here is a site that you can use to test out your regex: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html Go there an try your regex

Comment: @eugened  this is a very simple case for group reference. do some google, do some test. next time you met it again, you know how to handle. e.g. this could let u start : `{([^}]*)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [string replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function. Something like this:

```
yourString.replaceAll("\\{([^{}]*\\=\\=[^{}]*)\\}", "'$1', {$1}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no nested `{}`

```
str = str.replaceAll( "(?<=condition)\\s*(\\{([^}]+)\\})", " '$2', $1" );
```